# Why my accuracy does not increase in TFF with VGG16 model?

Tags: tensorflow-federated

I have build my code TFF with VGG16 model. However, at training time, my accuracy does not change and stays around 0.5 even after 11 rounds.
I have tried changing the learning rate but has no significant effect.!!!
So, What are the metrics and things that I can change in the code to increase the accuracy, because when I run my code, the accuracy is stable and don't increase!!

Here is the code of my VGG16

```
def create_compiled_keras_model():

    IMG_SHAPE = (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
    VGG16_MODEL = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                               include_top=False,
                                               weights='imagenet')

#VGG16_MODEL.trainable=False
    global_average_layer = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
    prediction_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(......)


    model = tf.keras.Sequential([ VGG16_MODEL, global_average_layer, prediction_layer ])


    model.compile  .............
    return model

...
iterative_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(model_fn)
state = iterative_process.initialize()
for round_num in range(2, 12):
  state, metrics = iterative_process.next(state, federated_train_data)
  print('round {:2d}, metrics={}'.format(round_num, metrics, state))
```

Comment: I read this in another post :  **I found that the initialization is the reason why ResNet has poor performance. It is possibly because that ttf uses relatively simple state initialization which doesn't consider some layers like batch norm, so when I assigned the normal Keras model initial weights to the server instead of using its default initialization, the federated results were much better.** but I can't understand how to applicate ?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would investigate here is: does this model train in a centralized way?

This can be answered by trying something like:

```
model = create_compiled_keras_model()
# Assumes client_data_object is tff.simulation.ClientData object
centralized_dataset = client_data_object.create_tf_dataset_from_all_clients()
model.fit(centralized_dataset, verbose=1)
```

If these numbers don't go down, it is unlikely that training the model in a federated way will cause convergence to occur.

You mention initialization may be an issue here; if this is the problem, it should show up here, as [TFF actually pulls the initialization off of the initialization encoded in the model_fn itself](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/framework/optimizer_utils.py#L229).

You also mention batch norm; anecdotally, I have not personally seen batch norm used in the federated setting well. We have seen group norm working in some vision tasks, but it may not be immediate to wire group norm into the VGG architecture depending on the API Keras exposes.

If these numbers *do* go down, then the first thing I would investigate in the federated setting would be setting the learning rate *much higher* (e.g. 2-3 orders of magnitude) than the one you see performing well in the centralized setting.

Comment: I think this is super close--if you have a `ClientData` object representing the users in your test set, you can use a function like [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/d5a88f5131424872672f89a667712916df4dc622/tensorflow_federated/python/research/optimization/shared/fed_avg_schedule.py#L90) to assign your tff learning models weights to a keras model with the same architecture, and call the `evaluate` method on this keras model--but I have a feeling you figured something like this out already!

Comment: I see the verbosity is 1 here; does it simply keep evaluating, like, evaluation is running but there is an infinite amount of data? This could happen depending on the contents of `emnist_test`. Try changing the `centralized_data` construction line to something like `centralized_data = emnist_test.create_tf_dataset_from_all_clients().take(N)` for some reasonable value of `N`; if this stops, then it is highly likely that your `centralized_data` here represents an infinite dataset.